# UI button shows on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a IU button that has an image, when I run on the simulator everything shows up and is working. however once I try to run on the device the button is not there. I already  checked for case sensitivity, if its in the bundle phase, changing the button from "weak" to "strong", checking the button alpha and still no luck. Any other suggestions? Thanks.

update.
so now I tried to delete the image and add text to the button to see if the button will show with text(on the device). The button is still visible on the simulator but on the device I get no text, no button. So now my question is, what could be possible reasons a UI button would show on the simulator but not the device?

I also used a previous app as a test, I added a button and ran it on the same device and the button showed up with the same image I am trying to implement. so I am lost as to why its not working on my current app.

Comment: Check the image name of your button.. Case sensitive matters when you test it on device..

Comment: did you check the case of the part after the `.`? For example, `.png` or `.PNG`

Comment: Did you check Retina/Non-Retina issue? Screen Size? iOS Version? Did you checked by breakpoint its frame, if its not null?

Comment: i checked for case sensitivity as far as the actual name of the button and the extension (ex .png .PNG) @GenieWanted

Comment: my button has a retina and non retina image. I also tested on several different simulators and the button shows up, once I go to the device no button. @Larme

Comment: hey I figured it out! first I added another button just to see if it would show up and it did! then I added a image to that unresponsive button to see what would happen and it showed up! so I knew I made an error somewhere while making my original button. So I guess I had to take a trail and error approach.